# WiFi transmit rate 702 Mbit, receive rate only 54 Mbit

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

With an TP-Link Archer T4U USB3 wireless adapter I get the following on 5Ghz in a Windows 10 Home Powershell.

netsh wlan show interfaces, results in this:

There is 1 interface on the system:

```
Name                   : Wi-Fi
Description            : TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter
GUID                   : ****
Physical address       : ****
State                  : connected
SSID                   : WiFi-Gast
BSSID                  : ****
Network type           : Infrastructure
Radio type             : 802.11ac
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
Connection mode        : Auto Connect
Channel                : 44
Receive rate (Mbps)    : 54
Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 702
Signal                 : 100%
Profile                : WiFi-Gast

Hosted network status  : Not available
```

I have a similar Linux setup in the same room and the device log shows most of the receive packets in between 400Mbit and 800 Mbit.

I know the AP is setup properly because with my laptop's internal Intel WiFi Card the connection is properly, 780 Mbit, both Receive and Transmit.

I just installed the latest driver from TP-Link, but the driver version drops from 1030.11.503.2016 to 1030.2.731.2015. So I reversed that.

I forgot to say that the initial seconds/minutes after connecting, both speeds of the TP-Link WiFi are high. Than the receive drops to 54 Mbit and never goes higher.
Whether it is wifi N / AC / 2.4 GHz or 5GHz, the receive speed drops to 54 Mbit.

I did a speed test with LANBench, between a Gigabit host as client and the TP-Link Archer T4U as server.

Results is a receive speed of ~190 Mbit and a received speed of only! 4 MBit.

I also did a Iperf3 speed test between a linux and windows client, with both a Archer T4U. Result was 90 Mbit.

---

**EDIT**: Now I found this thread, that discusses disabling QOS, which raised the speed to 156 MBit both ways. And it discusses a new driver that is not found otherwise.

Comment: 2.4Ghz network or 5Ghz network?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/678949/880618).

Comment: You might want to add that to your question. Try installing the latest [drivers](https://www.tp-link.com/us/download/Archer-T4U.html#Driver) released in 2016-12-23.

Comment: Confirm if yours is Realtek based, probably RTL8812AU. If so, try the newest generic drivers from Realtek. It should have no problems in desktop Linux. https://wikidevi.com/wiki/TP-LINK_Archer_T4U

Comment: yes, it is. I am not running Linux, but Windows.

Comment: Thanks now I found Realtek's generic 2018 drivers. google: rtl8812au driver windows 10

Comment: Unfortunately that package doesn't provide a newer driver than 2016 version.

Comment: Old question, but when you say “Now I found this thread…” what thread do you mean? I would be helpful if you were to provide a link to it. But like I said, this is an old thread so hey!

Answer (score 0):

If the RX stays at an 802.11 rate of 54, this means that your adapter is recording management or control packets sent by the AP to the client.  Those packets usually get sent at OFDM rates in 5GHz.

So, I would not worry to much if your RX rate is idle at 54 when your PC is idle. Now RX on the client means downstream traffic and TX on your client means Upstream. Most of the traffic on the internet is downstream to your client (still with me?).  When setting up iPerf, you must setup the server on your wireless client and the iPerf client on the wired network. This way when you push traffic to the wireless client, it'll be downstream traffic.

While the traffic is running, check netsh and see if the RX has increased.  Now please be aware that the driver algorithm for updating the 802.11 RX/TX rates are different for every client driver. Try a couple of times and see if the results are positive.

> WiredClient(iPerf Client)-----AP ((( ))) WirelessClient(iPerf Server)

Don't forget to add the -w 256k on both sides of your iPerf session to increase the TCP window size. This is necessary to get increased throughput.

Comment: I tested with iperf3 -P20 before and that got me 200MBit, on linux or windows. Those 20 streams increase bandwidth too.

Comment: the -P20 flag results in 50% more throughput than -w 256k.